# Extend jQueryUI Widget with own methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a widget, but coming from an OOP background, accessing methods via a function call to it seems strange.

```
// create the widget in target_id
myWidget = jQuery('#target_id').superWidget();

// this works and accesses do_something, but it's long and redundant.
// After all, myWidget is already a superWidget
myWidget.data('superWidget').do_something('hello');

// also works, but is awkward
myWidget.superWidget('do_something', 'hello');

// what I want to be able to do:
myWidget.do_something('hello');
```

I think it should be possible to do this by extending the widget with itself when _create is called, but I am not actually sure how to go about making it work.

Is it possible? How?
Is it a truly awful idea that I should avoid? Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we don't provide this API is because it creates collisions. What happens if the widget provides a method with the same name as an existing jQuery method? What happens if you initialize multiple widgets on the same element?

With that said, widgets are pure OO with a wrapper to provide the common jQuery API. If you want to just use the OO syntax, you can.

```
var widget = $.ns.superWidget( {}, "#elem" );
widget.doSomething( "hello" );
```

The `$.ns.superWidget` function is an actual constructor. Calling it as a function just results in another call with `new` to force the constructor behavior.

You might be interested in reading the [jQuery UI 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#improved-api-for-direct-instantiation) which lists out the various ways to directly construct widget instances.

*Note: If you're using jQuery UI 1.8.x, the element parameter won't accept a selector, you must pass a DOM element.*

Comment: I'm using 1.9, so that would work for me. That said, I also understand the reason why you wouldn't want it to act that way be default. Thank you for a concise and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the way you want to call a widget method is not supported jQueryUI Widget Factory interface.

http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/

Comment: I know it's not supported, I was wondering if it is possible to auto-extend the widget so that it would work in the case of the widget that I'm building.